# how can I put a if else statement for showing a loading screen in here flutter

Tags: flutter, swiper.js

how can I put an if-else statement for showing a loading screen in here flutter here is my code?
it's showing an error screen every time I reload my app but after a few seconds it displays all the data I want to put a loading indicator instead of showing that error screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  List users;
  Future<bool> _getposts() async {
    String serviceurl =
        "http://spiro-learn.herokuapp.com/api/video-list/?format=json";
    var response = await http.get(serviceurl);
    setState(() {
      users = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    });
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._getposts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        child: Swiper(
          itemWidth: 400,
          itemHeight: 300,
          layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          viewportFraction: 0.4,
          scale: 0.5,
          itemCount: users.length == null ? 0 : users.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(users[index]["title"]),
              subtitle: Text('${users[index]['likes']}'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  body: users == null? CircularProgressIndicator(): SizedBox(
    child: Swiper(
      itemWidth: 400,
      itemHeight: 300,
      layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      viewportFraction: 0.4,
      scale: 0.5,
      itemCount: users.length == null ? 0 : users.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(users[index]["title"]),
          subtitle: Text('${users[index]['likes']}'),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  List users;
  Future _future;
  Future<bool> _getposts() async {
    String serviceurl =
        "http://spiro-learn.herokuapp.com/api/video-list/?format=json";
    var response = await http.get(serviceurl);
    setState(() {
      users = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    });
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = _getposts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
          return SizedBox(
            child: Swiper(
              itemWidth: 400,
              itemHeight: 300,
              layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              viewportFraction: 0.4,
              scale: 0.5,
              itemCount: users.length == null ? 0 : users.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(users[index]["title"]),
                  subtitle: Text('${users[index]['likes']}'),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
            }
          }else
          return Center(child: 
          CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```